# Возможно ли описать сигнатуру Action<> с именами переменных?

Tags: c#

При формировании события удобно использовать делегат `Action<T1,T2>` 
При подписке на событие формируется функция с сигнатурой заданной делегатом, но названия переменных задаются автоматически и не совсем удобные.
Можно ли как то при описании делегата `Action<T1,T2>` задать имена переменным?

В идеале хотелось что то вроде

```
[Attribute("index", "countDevice", "temperature")]
public event Action<ushort, ushort, float> MyEvent;
```

тем самым код будет понятен для использования

Comment: какие переменные имеются ввиду? добавьте пример кода

Comment: @Grundy, видимо, имеются в виду названия параметров метода.

Comment: Чтобы IDE подсказывала при вызове invoke? вряд ли такое возможно.

Comment: И еще, для событий лучше использовать типы [EventHandler{T}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [EventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Vlad не лучше. Зачастую эти события избыточны или, наоборот, слишком простые. `EventHandler` - вообще пример того как делать не надо...

Comment: @PavelMayorov встречал обратную точку зрения в гайдах и считаю, что она верна. поэтому в event придерживаюсь создания аргументов. После добавления параметров в аргументах старый код будет работать. С Action же придется добавлять параметр и старый код чинить везде.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я больше придерживаюсь точки зрения гайдлайнов. Нет никакого смысла использовать для событий Action. EventHandler и EventHandler{T} вполне подходят для всех случаев. А еще хуже, на мой взгляд, выдумывать свои делегаты на ровном месте.

Comment: ну вы можете написать свой атрибут

Comment: @vitidev Да, добавление параметра может быть проблемой. Но это проблема для библиотек, в своих проектах добавить параметр довольно просто, пусть и с изменением старого кода.

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно задать имена параметров делегата - проще всего создать свой тип делегата. Можно прямо рядом с самим событием:

```
public delegate void FooHandler(Bar bar, Baz baz);
public event FooHandler Foo;
```

Если задача допускает одни и те же имена параметров у разных событий - можно сделать свой обобщенный делегат:

```
public delegate void GenericEventHandler<T1, T2> (T1 sender, T2 e);

// ...

public event GenericEventHandler<Bar, Baz> Foo;
```

Также можно поискать готовые делегаты с подходящими именами параметров. Например, есть такой редко используемый делегат [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Я понимаю что можно явно описать делегат, но каждый раз придумывать имена для делегатов которые в принципе не нужны, трата времени. Я думал может быть через атрибуты как то описать имена переменных.

Comment: Имя для делегата - это имя события + `Handler` или `EventHandler`. Ничего придумывать не надо, можно сниппет создать, чтобы создавать сразу событие и делегат к нему.

Comment: Причем тут Event Handler? Мне нужна своя сигнатура.

Comment: Я говорю о выборе имени для делегата. Чем не устраивает способ "взять имя события и дописать в конец Handler"?

Comment: Можно, но хотелось этого избежать. Ответ в принципе получен, всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую описать имена нельзя.
Но можно смягчить проблему, используя xml-комментарии:

```
/// <summary>
/// <para>Имя и описание первого аргумента.</para>
/// <para>Имя и описание второго аргумента.</para>
/// <para>Имя и описание третьего аргумента.</para>
/// </summary>
public event Action<ushort, ushort, float> MyEvent;
```

Будет выводиться подсказка на MyEvent.